# In text classification, how can I use a neural network on word embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have read some papers on text classification but they are pretty abstract. **I fail at understanding how to train** a multi layer perceptron with data made of sentences -> label.

A perceptron takes a vector input of size m and outputs a vector.

As a first step I reduced the dimensions and I map each word to a vector of n features, where n is a constant.

Now how do I mix the words in a sentence to make an input of size m ? Each word maps to a vector of size n but then what ? Knowing that every sentence has a different number of words.

Thanks

Comment: You can [embed the entire text](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a118/24e868ff48a3f1b16d80d984e5f68c14c6e2.pdf) [PDF] ...

Comment: see the section "the dog is on the table" from this link
https://machinelearnings.co/text-classification-using-neural-networks-f5cd7b8765c6
it illustrates what described from previous answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. These are the steps to follow.

- Pad your sentences to a fixed length. Use the maximum length. If you are comfortable with creating buckets, you can pad the sentences to maximum length for individual bucket. To pad, add  PAD tokens to each sentence till they become the size of the fixed sequence length you want to use.
- Extract the unique words out of the padded corpus and assign a numeric id to every word. You can use there index in the unique list as IDs. Filtering out rare words and replacing them with unknown token will prove useful.
- Now if you had a sentence like "I am John", and your maximum sequence length was 5 the sentence will become, "I am John PAD PAD." Once you extract the unique words, you can represent the sentence as IDs like [1,2,3,4,4] Now if you had 100 sentences you will have a matrix of size 100 X 5.

  - Now you can go in two ways, represent each word as a one hot vector i.e.a vectors of zeros with a one at the index it represents or a simpler way would be to train a word embedding.

For details look into [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/&ved=0ahUKEwib7PPGhrjRAhXIMY8KHQhrAuEQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNF3HZnrONtqhVKMnjlyiBYcPg654w&sig2=y6xkPfvyxPrnQ41HAGH1sw) RNN tutorial by Denny Britz, this is from scratch.

If you are of the deep learning persuasaion then check out Denny Britz's CNN text classification [tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/&ved=0ahUKEwjngfbrhrjRAhUSUI8KHf2nCaUQFggfMAA&usg=AFQjCNFfCQwHiPUd3lNXTvUXgh0g7xYhCw&sig2=HwdGfSDELpDjPOKz9P4EpA) where he uses tensorflow and trains his own word embedding. The first blog will give you all the information you need on how to prepare your text dataset.

Comment: I understand all of your bullet-points. Could you elaborate on how basically replacing a word in a sequence of words (a sentence) with an arbitrary integer number trains a model? Ex: 1, 2, 3 represent "I", "am", "john" but "john" - a 3 - is not necessarily better (or worse) than "I" - a 1 - so I'm wondering what an algorithm does with this data that looks ordinal in-nature?

Comment: Its not a random integer number, and you dont use the integer, you use a one hot encoded representation which means , each word is represented by a vector of the vocabulary size with one at the index, ( the number) and zero everywhere else, which turns it into sequential data. Its a bag of words representation and no semantic information is encoded and therefore I suggest using word2vec representation. So you are right to think that the data is ordinal but it is a sequence of ordinal data. I hope your question is answered.

Comment: Hey @HimanshuRai, do you know of good article explaining how to implement work embedding?

Comment: Tensorflow has a word embedding tutorial in their github repository. You can find plenty of implementations on github.